How can I make a PDF chatbot that keeps the context of each access separate?
I’m a beginner user of Streamlit and I’ve created a chatbot with Gemini to ask questions in the context of .PDF files. The deploy was done in the Streamlit Community Cloud
The Github is here (app.py). It works well, but I’ve noticed that when two or more users use the site at the same time, the context of the answers is mixed up
That is, user 1 uploads a PDF and starts asking the model questions about a topic. Then user 2, on another computer, uploads another PDF on another subject. User 1’s answers start to have user 2’s context
So I want to know if Streamlit can isolate the context of each user who uses the chatbot.
Edited:
The entire script:
# Import the necessary libraries
import streamlit as st
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings, ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
import google.generativeai as genai
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS 
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from google.generativeai.types.safety_types import HarmBlockThreshold, HarmCategory
from langchain_community.output_parsers.rail_parser import GuardrailsOutputParser
import asyncio

# Function to extract text from several PDF documents
def get_pdf_text(pdf_docs):
    text = ""
    for pdf in pdf_docs:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf) # Initialize a PDF reader for each document
        for page in pdf_reader.pages: # Iterate on each PDF page
            text += page.extract_text() # Extract the text from the page and add it to the text variable
    return text # Returns the concatenated text of all PDFs

# Function to split the text into parts that are easier to manage and process
def get_text_chunks(text):
    # Configure the text splitter to split the text into chunks, each up to 10,000 characters long, with an overlap of 1,000 characters
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=10000, chunk_overlap=1000)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text) # Split the text into parts (chunks)
    return chunks

# Function to create a vector store from text chunks
def get_vector_store(text_chunks, api_key):
    embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001", api_key=api_key) # Load the embedding model
    vector_store = FAISS.from_texts(text_chunks, embedding=embeddings) # Create a FAISS vector store from the text blocks
    vector_store.save_local("faiss_index") # Save the vector store locally for later use

# Function to create a chain of conversational responses using a template
def get_conversational_chain(api_key):
    # Detailed instructions on chatbot operation and response format - in Brazilian Portuguese and for types of documents of public interest in the country
    instructions = """
    Sempre termine as respostas com "Todas as informações precisam ser checadas com as fontes das informações".
    Você é um assistente para analisar documentos .PDF com um contexto jornalístico. Por exemplo: 
    documentos da Lei nº 12.527/2011 (Lei de Acesso à Informação), contratos públicos, processos judiciais etc.
    Explique os passos de forma simples. Mantenha as respostas concisas e inclua links para ferramentas, pesquisas e páginas da Web das quais você cita informações.
    Quando o usuário pedir recursos, certifique-se de que cita as ligações para a investigação ou exemplos.
    Se eu lhe pedir para resumir uma passagem, escreva-a ao nível universitário
    Quando for relevante, divida os tópicos em partes mais pequenas e fáceis de entender. Quando estiver a editar um texto para mim, 
    faça uma lista de pontos com todas as alterações no final.
    Antes de começar uma tarefa, respire fundo e execute-a passo a passo.
    Seja claro, breve e ordenado nas respostas. Seja direto e claro.
    Evite opiniões e tente ser neutro.
    Se baseie nas classes processuais do Direito no Brasil que estão neste site -  https://www.cnj.jus.br/sgt/consulta_publica_classes.php
    Se não souber a resposta diga que não sabe
    
    Quando analisar documentos de processos judiciais procure priorizar nos resumos:
    - Verifique se é uma petição inicial, decisão ou sentença
    - Faça uma apresentação da ação e de suas partes: breve síntese do processo e de seus pólos ativo e passivo, indicando o tipo de processo, advogados e magistrados
    - Motivos que levaram o autor a ajuizar a ação: explicação sucinta do porquê de o autor ter proposto a ação em face do réu
    - O que o autor requereu com a ação: citação de todos os requerimentos e pedidos que o autor realizou através do processo, tanto liminarmente quanto no mérito
    - Resultado das decisões: exposição do que foi decidido nas decisões interlocutórias (liminares) e na sentença
    - Status: Ao final do resumo é importante que se indique o status do processo

    Quando analisar documentos de licitações ou contratos públicos, saiba isto:
    As licitações públicas no Brasil são um processo administrativo formal e transparente, utilizado pela administração pública para contratar bens, serviços ou obras. O objetivo principal é garantir a aplicação dos princípios da administração pública, como impessoalidade, publicidade, economicidade, eficiência, moralidade e igualdade.
Etapas do Processo Licitatório:
    Fase Preparatória: A administração pública define a necessidade de contratar um bem, serviço ou obra e elabora o edital da licitação, que contém todas as regras e procedimentos do processo.
    Divulgação do Edital: O edital é publicado em diário oficial e em outros meios de comunicação, para que empresas e pessoas interessadas possam tomar conhecimento e participar da licitação.
    Apresentação de Propostas: As empresas e pessoas interessadas apresentam suas propostas, que devem atender às exigências do edital.
    Julgamento das Propostas: Uma comissão de licitação analisa as propostas e seleciona a mais vantajosa para a administração pública, levando em consideração critérios como preço, qualidade, prazo e experiência do licitante.
    Adjudicação e Contratação: A administração pública adjudica o contrato à empresa vencedora da licitação e formaliza o contrato.
    Execução do Contrato: A empresa vencedora executa o contrato, fornecendo o bem, serviço ou obra contratado.
    Fiscalização e Recebimento: A administração pública fiscaliza a execução do contrato e recebe o bem, serviço ou obra, após verificar se está de acordo com o contratado.
Modalidades de Licitação:
A Lei de Licitações e Contratos (Lei nº 14.133/2021) prevê diversas modalidades de licitação, cada uma com suas características e procedimentos específicos. As modalidades mais comuns são:
    Pregão: Modalidade mais rápida e simples, utilizada para compras de bens e serviços de valor pequeno ou médio.
    Concorrência: Modalidade utilizada para compras de bens e serviços de valor elevado, obras públicas e serviços de engenharia.
    Tomada de Preços: Modalidade utilizada para contratação de obras públicas e serviços de engenharia de valor pequeno ou médio.
    Concurso: Modalidade utilizada para a seleção de projetos técnicos, científicos ou artísticos.
    Leilão: Modalidade utilizada para a venda de bens públicos, como imóveis e veículos.
Importância das Licitações Públicas:
As licitações públicas são importantes para garantir:
    Transparência: O processo licitatório é público e transparente, o que permite que qualquer cidadão possa acompanhar as etapas do processo e fiscalizar a utilização dos recursos públicos.
    Competitividade: As empresas e pessoas interessadas competem entre si para apresentar a proposta mais vantajosa para a administração pública, o que garante a obtenção de melhores preços e serviços.
    Eficiência: A administração pública contrata o bem, serviço ou obra que melhor atende às suas necessidades, com o melhor custo-benefício.
    Moralidade: O processo licitatório contribui para prevenir a corrupção e o favorecimento de empresas ou pessoas específicas.
Onde Obter Mais Informações:
Para mais informações sobre licitações públicas no Brasil, você pode consultar os seguintes sites:
    Portal da Transparência: https://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/
    Ministério da Economia: https://www.gov.br/economia/pt-br
    Tribunal de Contas da União: https://www.TCU.gov.br/

    No Brasil, o termo mais comum para se referir a licitações sem concorrentes é inexigibilidade ou dispensa de licitação.
Este termo está previsto na Lei de Licitações e Contratos (Lei nº 14.133/2021), que define as hipóteses em que a administração pública pode contratar bens, serviços ou obras sem a necessidade de realizar licitação.
Outras expressões que podem ser utilizadas para se referir a licitações sem concorrentes:
    Licitação deserta: Essa expressão é utilizada para indicar que a licitação não teve nenhum participante, ou seja, nenhuma empresa apresentou proposta.
    Licitação única: Essa expressão é utilizada para indicar que apenas uma empresa apresentou proposta, o que significa que a licitação não foi competitiva.
    Contratação direta: Essa expressão é utilizada para se referir à modalidade de contratação que a administração pública pode utilizar em casos de inexigibilidade de licitação.
É importante ressaltar que a inexigibilidade de licitação não é sinônimo de falta de transparência ou de controle. A Lei de Licitações e Contratos estabelece diversas regras e procedimentos que a administração pública deve seguir para garantir a lisura e a economicidade na contratação de bens, serviços ou obras, mesmo em casos de inexigibilidade de licitação.
Alguns exemplos de situações em que a inexigibilidade de licitação pode ser aplicada:
    Aquisição de bens ou serviços com fornecedor único: Quando existe apenas um único fornecedor para o bem ou serviço que a administração pública precisa adquirir, a licitação torna-se inviável.
    Contratação em caso de emergência: Em situações de urgência ou calamidade pública, a administração pública pode contratar bens, serviços ou obras sem licitação, para garantir o atendimento imediato das necessidades da população.
    Contratação de serviços artísticos ou culturais: A Lei de Licitações e Contratos permite a contratação direta de artistas ou profissionais de cultura, sem a necessidade de licitação, para a realização de obras de arte, espetáculos ou outros eventos culturais.

    Os documentos que trazem respostas de um pedido de acesso à informação pela Lei nº 12.527/2011 (LAI - Lei de Acesso à Informação) normalmente possuem:
- Nome do órgão público
- Nomes dos setores do órgão público responsáveis pelas informações
- Assunto
- Resumo da demanda
- Informações complementares
- Nomes das pessoas responsáveis pela resposta do pedido da LAI
- Data da resposta
É importante que a análise dos documentos que citam a LAI feita por este chatbot tragam informações:
- Data
- Protocolo NUP
- Nome do órgão público
- Nomes das pessoas responsáveis pela resposta do pedido da LAI
- Data da resposta
- E demais informações de resumo que demonstrem se o pedido da LAI foi totalmente atendido, parcialmente ou foi negado

    """

    prompt_template = f"""
    {instructions}
    Contexto:\n{{context}}\n
    Questão: \n{{question}}\n

    Resposta:
    """
    
    # Load the conversational AI model with the specified security settings
    model = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-1.0-pro", 
                                   temperature=0,
                                   candidate_count=1,
                                   safety_settings = {
                                       HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
                                       HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
                                       HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
                                       HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
                                       HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH
                                      }, 
                                  api_key=api_key)
    
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]) # Configure the prompt template
    chain = load_qa_chain(model, chain_type="stuff", prompt=prompt) # Load the Q&A string with the template and prompt
    return chain

# Function to process user input and generate responses
def user_input(user_question, api_key):
    if 'history' not in st.session_state: # Initialize session history, if not already present
        st.session_state.history = []

    embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001", api_key=api_key) # Load embeddings
    new_db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings, allow_dangerous_deserialization=True) # Load the local FAISS index
    docs = new_db.similarity_search(user_question) # Perform similarity search with user question
    chain = get_conversational_chain(api_key) # Get the conversation chain

    # Get a response from the chatbot
    response = chain({"input_documents": docs, "question": user_question}, return_only_outputs=True) 
    st.session_state.history.append({"question": user_question, "answer": response["output_text"]}) # Attach the interaction to the history
    
    for interaction in st.session_state.history:
        st.write(f":bust_in_silhouette: {interaction['question']}") # Show the question
        st.write(f"{interaction['answer']}") # Show the answer

# Main function for configuring the Streamlit application
def main():   
    st.set_page_config(page_title="Chatbot com vários PDFs", page_icon=":books:")
    st.header("Chatbot com vários PDFs :books:")

    with st.sidebar:
        st.title("Menu:")
        st.markdown("""
        - Se encontrar erros de processamento, reinicie com F5.
        """)
        
        st.warning(
            """
        Atenção: Os documentos que você compartilhar com o modelo de IA generativa podem ser usados pelo Gemini para treinar o sistema. Portanto, evite compartilhar documentos PDF que contenham:
        1. Dados bancários e financeiros
        2. Dados de sua própria empresa
        3. Informações pessoais
        4. Informações de propriedade intelectual
        5. Conteúdos autorais
        
        E não use IA para escrever um texto inteiro! O auxílio é melhor para gerar resumos, filtrar informações ou auxiliar a entender contextos - que depois devem ser checados. Inteligência Artificial comete erros!
        
        Este projeto não se responsabiliza pelos conteúdos criados a partir deste site.
        """
            )
        st.sidebar.title("Sobre este app")
        st.sidebar.info(
            "Este aplicativo foi desenvolvido por Reinaldo Chaves. "
            "Para mais informações, contribuições e feedback, visite o repositório do projeto: "
            "[GitHub](https://github.com/reichaves/chatgeminipdfs)."
        )

    
    # Create a new loop if there isn't an existing one
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if loop.is_closed():
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    # Field to enter the Gemini API Key
    if "api_key" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.api_key = ""
    if "uploaded_pdfs" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.uploaded_pdfs = []

    if not st.session_state.api_key:
        st.write("Digite sua API Key do Gemini")
        api_key = st.text_input("API Key do Gemini", type="password")
        st.markdown(
            f'<p style="font-size:18px;">Veja como obter uma API Key neste <a href="https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/api-key?hl=pt-br">site</a>!</p>',
            unsafe_allow_html=True)
        if api_key:
            st.session_state.api_key = api_key

    # Upload PDF documents
    if not st.session_state.uploaded_pdfs:
        st.write("Por favor, faça o upload e processe os documentos PDF para ativar o chat")
        pdf_docs = st.file_uploader("Carregar PDFs", type=["pdf"], accept_multiple_files=True)
        if pdf_docs:
            st.session_state.uploaded_pdfs = pdf_docs

    if st.session_state.api_key and st.session_state.uploaded_pdfs:
        genai.configure(api_key=st.session_state.api_key)
        #st.write(f"Chave API fornecida: {api_key}")  # Adding a debug log
        
        with st.sidebar:           
            if st.session_state.uploaded_pdfs:
                with st.spinner("Processando..."):
                    raw_text = get_pdf_text(st.session_state.uploaded_pdfs)
                    text_chunks = get_text_chunks(raw_text)
                    get_vector_store(text_chunks, st.session_state.api_key)
                    st.success("Done")
                    st.session_state['docs_processed'] = True
            else:
                st.error("Por favor, faça o upload de pelo menos um arquivo PDF antes de processar.")
    
        if st.session_state['docs_processed']:
            user_question = st.text_input("Faça perguntas para 'entrevistar' o PDF (por exemplo, processos judicias, contratos públicos, respostas da LAI etc). Se citar siglas nas perguntas coloque - a sigla e o seu significado. Atenção: Todas as respostas precisam ser checadas!", key="user_question_input")
            if user_question:
                user_input(user_question, st.session_state.api_key)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() 


Thanks @DarkBee So I'd better put all my code in the question?

Where do you deploy this app?

I mean do you deploy this app in streamlit community cloud? or digitalocean, etc?

Thansk @ferdy - streamlit community cloud

The issue with your app is this:
vector_store.save_local("faiss_index") # Save the vector store locally for later use
Your vector store is the container in the streamlit server. This is a common container for your users. The vectors are replaced whenever users uploaded new pdf. Try to make a research on storing the vectors in the session state, because session state is unique for every users. One thing, do you store the pdf per user? Store means you have a dedicated storage system to manage the pdf per user so that if they comeback next week, their pdf can be retrieved and continue to use.

Thank you very much @ferdy it makes perfect sense. I don't store PDFs. I thought the Streamlit user would get a separate session. I'll keep researching if there's a solution or I'll give up on Streamlit

Yes, streamlit users have separate sessions. But stored objects can be accessed by everybody. That is what happens when your load the locally stored vectors in new_db = FAISS.load_local(()
You can store your vector store to something like this.
st.session_state['vector_store'] = vector_store

Thank you very much @ferdy I did the test and it seems to have worked. In function get_vector_store, the vector store is saved to st.session_state['vector_store']. In function  user_input, the vector store is retrieved from st.session_state['vector_store'] - Should I change my script in the question?

"Should I change my script in the question?" If you have the solution, it is better that you will make a new post as an answer. This way, people would know what is the question and what is the answer or how it is solved. When we faced similar issues in the future we can take your post as reference.

This is the answer with the support of @ferdy
To fix the issue of context mixing between different users in my Streamlit app, I can use st.session_state to store the vector store for each session uniquely. This way, each user's data is isolated within their own session, preventing context contamination between users

Store Vector Store in Session State:
Modify the get_vector_store function to store the vector store in the session state instead of saving it locally:
st.session_state['vector_store'] = vector_store  # Store the vector store in the session state instead of saving it locally

Load Vector Store from Session State:
Update the user_input function to load the vector store from the session state
vector_store = st.session_state['vector_store']




I’ve noticed that when two or more users use the site at the same
time, the context of the answers is mixed up That is, user 1 uploads a
PDF and starts asking the model questions about a topic. Then user 2,
on another computer, uploads another PDF on another subject. User 1’s
answers start to have user 2’s context

to solver this, each pdf should be stored in PDF table and have relation with user. So, in your app,you should keep track of pdf's that created by the user.
There is a one-to-many relationship between User and Pdf, meaning one user can have multiple PDFs, but each PDF is associated with only one user. In PDF table, there shold be user_id Foregin Key field referencing user.id. That way each entry in the PDF table is associated with a specific entry in the User table through the user_id field.
You should be integrating sql database in your app and setting the correct relation between PDF and User tables. streamlit has docs for connecting to different sql databases.
